# Converting a base10 number to a baseN number using a custom alphabet of size N (Scala)

Tags: java, scala, math

What I want to achieve is to change the textual representation of positive integers by using a custom alphabet (which can be any arbitrary subset of UTF-8 characters) instead of the digits 0-9. I guess this is the same thing as converting  base10 numbers to baseN numbers using an alphabet of size N instead of A-Z and 0-9.

In Scala/Java, it is not difficult to convert base10 numbers to other bases (e.g. by using `Integer.toString(number, radix)` ), but the upper limit is base36 and there is no way to use custom characters. Is there an elegant way to do that?

Comment: My recommendation would be to look at the (open) source for a java port to determine how they do it and then override that method with your own that implements what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala won't do this for you.

But the math is pretty straightforward as long as your number is in a numeric representation (like a Long).  I'm going consider only the positive case here; the negative requires a few minus signs.

```
def baseString(number: Long): String = {
  var x = number
  var myDigits = List.empty[Char]
  while (x > 0) {
    myDigits = lookup(x % base) :: myDigits
    x = x / base
  }
  myDigits.mkString
}
```

Now you have a list containing the digits of your number (in order), assuming that `lookup` is a function that takes the value of the digit and produces the character representation.

To read out the number, it's the same thing backwards.  If your digits are already in a list, then

```
def stringBase(text: String): Long = {
  var x = 0L    // Assuming Long, but pick the right type
  var dig = text.toList
  while (dig.nonEmpty) {
    x = x * base + reverseLookup(dig.head)
    dig = dig.tail
  }
  x
}
```

And now you've got your number back.  (`reverseLookup` takes the character and produces the corresponding numeric value.)

You can test with the following (though you probably would want to throw exceptions on invalid values):

```
val base = 2
def lookup(i: Long) = i match { case 0 => 'f'; case _ => 't' }
def reverseLookup(c: Char) = c match { case 'f' => 0L; case _ => 1L }
```

Comment: @Rex Kerr is there a way to make this work with *both* positive and negative numbers? At the moment, I'm using a modification of your version. In case of a `Long`, I'm just adding an additional 65th bit an the front which makes everything a positive number. The downsides are that a) since the 65 bit doesn't fit into the `Long`, I need to use a `BigInt` and b) since the 65th bit of the number is always 1, the resulting string is in some cases longer that it needs to be.

Comment: (not in some cases, but in nearly all cases is what I wanted to say).